# Add new email using cpanel to an already configured outlook.com account

Tags: cpanel, microsoft-account, outlook.com

I have a custom domain whose email addresses are configured using the old outlook domain.
Now since Microsoft doesn't allow to add new accounts, therefore I was maintaining my old ones only.

Now if I add a new email account using cpanel will It affect my already existing account on MS outlook ? (I just want some dummy accounts for now)

Comment: Your question is very confusing. If you are the owner of a domain that has e-mail through the cpanel, then just make new accounts. Microsoft has no hold over you making new e-mail addresses with your own mail-server. If you are unsure if making e-mail accounts in your mail-server will affect Outlook on your personal computer, no it will have no effect, nothing will happen until you add the account to Outlook and even then, it's just one more e-mail account. More clarification of the question would help me answer this in a more direct fashion.

Comment: You're right, it's sort of confusing. Will making new accounts affect my already configured emails with outlook ?

Comment: And it's outlook.com not the outlook application.

Comment: @Daniel yes. Currently outlook.com doesn't allow free custom-domain linking without using office365. Existing accounts work as they used to though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.

Basically I'll need to update my MX record back to my own domain rather than of domain.live.com

Even If I add new emails, Microsoft will reject incoming emails for them since I haven't added them up in the domain.live.com admin account.

MX records are used to update DNS records to redirect emails for a custom domain to another domain.